# What Superman comic "proved" Clark Kent is not Superman using a cardboard cut-out?

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

I'm looking for a Superman comic that I saw years ago. I'm guessing it was first published in the 70s or early 80s.

The premise was that in order to prove to others that Superman and Clark Kent could be seen in the same room together (to protect his secret identity), Superman created a cardboard cut-out of the Clark Kent identity placed in front of a news camera, while Superman zoomed around in the background.

Does anyone recall which comic this was?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're referring to Superman #291 story '**[The Time-Powered Peril!](http://www.comicvine.com/superman-291-the-time-powered-peril/4000-15555/)**' first published in September 1975.

Both Superman and Clark are involved in filming a commercial for "*Rolova*" watches. Superman switches places with a cardboard cutout of Clark Kent which apparently fools the viewing audience because they're all wearing 3D glasses.

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Bingo! That's the one! Thank you!

Comment: @ForceFlow - No one is useless in this world who lightens the burdens of another.